# How to make a list of checked checkboxes in pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I have more than 10 checkboxes.

I need to make a list of checked checkboxes by user, as each checked box has its own function that depends on the number of checked checkboxes!.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thanks for your time.
I solve it in an easy way,
I make a list

```
List = [(self.chckbox_name.isChecked() , "#name or string I need to be returned if condition is true") , ...etc ]

List_of_checked =[] 

List_of_unchecked = []

for i, v in List: 
      if i == True:
              List_of_checked.append (v)
      else:
              List_of_unchecked.append (v)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.listCheckBox = ["Checkbox_1", "Checkbox_2", "Checkbox_3", "Checkbox_4", "Checkbox_5",
                             "Checkbox_6", "Checkbox_7", "Checkbox_8", "Checkbox_9", "Checkbox_10" ]
        self.listLabel    = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ] 
        grid = QGridLayout()

        for i, v in enumerate(self.listCheckBox):
            self.listCheckBox[i] = QCheckBox(v)
            self.listLabel[i] = QLabel()
            grid.addWidget(self.listCheckBox[i], i, 0)
            grid.addWidget(self.listLabel[i],    i, 1)

        self.button = QPushButton("Check CheckBox")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.checkboxChanged)
        self.labelResult = QLabel()

        grid.addWidget(self.button,     10, 0, 1,2)     
        grid.addWidget(self.labelResult,11, 0, 1,2)  
        self.setLayout(grid)        

    def checkboxChanged(self):
        self.labelResult.setText("")
        for i, v in enumerate(self.listCheckBox):
            self.listLabel[i].setText("True" if v.checkState() else "False")
            self.labelResult.setText("{}, {}".format(self.labelResult.text(),
                                                     self.listLabel[i].text()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    clock = Window()
    clock.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]